# Why does adding items make Paypal Checkout return an error?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to create a PayPal order using the Javascript SDK. I am unable to add items without PayPal returning a non-descriptive 400 error.

This markup works fine:

```
return actions.order.create({
  purchase_units: [{
    description: "Stuff",
    amount: {
      value: '57.49',
      currency_code: "CAD",
    },
  }],
  application_context: {
    brand_name: "MyBusiness",
    shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING'
  }
});
```

This markup, where I add the amount breakdown and items doesn't:

```
return actions.order.create({
  purchase_units: [{
    description: "Stuff",
    amount: {
      value: '57.49',
      currency_code: "CAD",
      breakdown: {
        item_total: '57.49',
      }
    },
    items: [{
      unit_amount: '57.49',
      quantity: '1',
      name: "item 1",
    }],
  }],
  application_context: {
    brand_name: "MyBusiness",
    shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING'
  }
});
```

I am following this documentation:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-purchase_unit_request

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-item

I'm guessing the way I added the breakdown doesn't work. But the spec implies that it is amount -> breakdown.

Answer (score 0):

2024 edit: actions.order.create is deprecated, the payload of v2/checkout/orders create should only be sent from a server. See the standard integration guide: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/

application_context is also deprecated, use `payment_source.paypal.experience_context` instead (see the [API reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create))

```json
{
      "purchase_units": [{
          "description": "Stuff",
          "amount": {
            "value": "57.49",
            "currency_code": "CAD",
            "breakdown": {
              "item_total": {
                "currency_code": "CAD",
                "value": "57.49"
              },
            }
          },
          "items": [
            {
              "unit_amount": {
                "currency_code": "CAD",
                "value": "57.49"
              },
              "quantity": "1",
              "name": "item 1",
            },
          ],
        }
      ],
      "application_context": {
        "shipping_preference": 'NO_SHIPPING'
      }
}
```